# Nodejs crashes while calling bash script that runs cpp binary

Tags: node.js, node-modules

Hi I am trying to call a script from node js api when I receive a image on the API however the app keeps on crashing when trying to call a bash script. The app basically receives an image and writes to a local directory and I want to run a model on it.
My bash script is simple and runs a binary model. I tested my script by running it manually and it works fine so there is no issue with the script.

> > node: ../deps/uv/src/unix/core.c:113: uv_close: Assertion `!uv__is_closing(handle)' failed.

sometimes I get this error:

> > node: ../deps/uv/src/unix/core.c:180: uv_close: Assertion `0' failed.

```
// multer to upload image
const multer = require('multer');

const fs = require('fs');


module.exports = {
    uploadImage: (req, res) => {
        let tmp_path = req.files[0].path;
        var target_path = '/opt/cast_image.jpg';
        console.log("target path is "+ target_path)
        var src = fs.createReadStream(tmp_path);
        var dest = fs.createWriteStream(target_path);
        src.pipe(dest);
        src.on('end', function() {
        const { exec } = require('child_process');
         exec('sh run_model.sh.signed /opt/cast_image.jpg &', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
                  if (err) {
                    //some err occurred
                    console.error(err)
                  } else {
                   // the *entire* stdout and stderr (buffered)
                   console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
                   console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
                  }
                });
        res.sendStatus(200);
        });
        src.on('error', function(err) { res.sendStatus(500); });

    }
}
```

My bash script that I am trying to run:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /usr/apps/outpainting-native-tester/bin/
./outpainting-native-tester migan $1
```